# How to change the column letter in a formula when dragging down?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

How do you increment the column letter ( I, J, K, L, ...... U, V) when dragging the formula down?

This is my formula so far:

```
=COUNTIF(I$54:I$62,"Yes")
```

Comment: @pnuts Just to increase every time, i.e. I, J, K, L, ...... U, V

Comment: @pnuts Lol thanks anyway :), looks like my only option :'D

Comment: @rwking I need the column to change so this wont help :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is to find the unicode number for the column letter and increment it when dragging down. In this case, I used "73" for the letter "i". This will work as long as your data doesn't go past column Z. Definitely not the prettiest formula, but this formula will work in this situation.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CHAR(ROWS($54:54)-1+73)&"54:"&CHAR(ROWS($54:54)-1+73)&"64"),"Yes")
```

[image]

The best way to do this formula though and the most robust would be to use INDEX. With INDEX you can lookup a whole column and you will get the same results as the previous formula plus there is no limitation to what the size of your data set can be:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($I$54:$V$62,,ROWS($54:54)),"Yes")
```

[image]

Comment: Awsome thanks, but i got to do this in 2 other locations, so could you explain how to make it for myself

Comment: You can pretty much use the same formula in the second example above and use the image below it to line up your new ranges. The first parameter of INDEX is just your data table (Be sure and lock the range with the "$" signs). The second parameter of INDEX you can leave blank. This tells the INDEX formula that there is no specific row number that you want to  look up, and that you instead want to look all of them up. The last parameter in INDEX is the column number that you want to look up. I use an expandable range here that increments by one as you drag it down.